# Get reference variable from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, reference

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88256ea59ecdeae948cf664b477e113d7263f2c8

As you can see I use $this->options as input value.
What I'm trying to achieve here is getting option from value by key name and return it.

That is the easy part, but what I want to do with variable from returnOption is setting new key on it and see changes in $this->options array.

How can I archieve this?

Comment: Why can't you do this: `$op =$this->options[$optionName];`??

Comment: You need to be more clear.  What is an example of what `$this->options` contains and what you would like it to contain?  Also, for it's purpose, there is no need for a loop in that function, just `if(isset($options[$optionName])) { return $options[$optionName]; }`

Comment: Actually $this->options has option, which may have children options. so returnContent is actually recursive function that searches throught options. Now I need a way to change options value and this should be done outside the function. So I made simplified version of my mission to get understanding how to archieve this with one-dimensional array.

Comment: Well, I got my answer, but why is this off-topic? I have code in link, I have major level question (in topic) and specific question about my exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function & returnOption(&$options, $optionName)
{
   foreach($options as $key => &$value) 
   {
      if($key === $optionName) 
          return $value;
   }
}

$op =& $this->returnOption($this->options, $optionName);
$op['newValue'] = 'value';
var_dump($this->options);
```

Something like that should work. Then again, $this->options should probably be some sort of object with proper accessors for the options you're trying to get to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. About options being object - I accept it as a great advice, but I would prefer not do this way and now curiousity is higher than ever how to accomplish this.
Unfortunately your code didn't work.
Test online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88256ea59ecdeae948cf664b477e113d7263f2c8

Comment: You need to pass the $options to the function as a reference as well (so you don't get a copy-on-write) and clarify that you're also expecting a reference when calling it ($op =& etc). Should work like this.